# Good recommendations to study Algebraic logic

Tags: reference-request, logic, first-order-logic, book-recommendation, algebraic-logic

I've asked before about good recommendations to study algebra for the sake of algebraic logic and I've got very good recommendations.

I wonder if you have some recommendations to start studying algeraic logic itself.

I've come across  some books but not sure which one to start with.

Now, What do you recommend? and why?

Some of the books that I've seen are:

- *A**n Algebraic introduction to mathematical logic***, Barnes
- **The Mathematics of Metamathematics**, Helena Rasiowa & Roman Sikorski
- ***An Algebraic approach to non-classical logics***, Rasiowa
- ***Algebraic logic***, Andreka and Monk
- ***Algebraic logic***, Halmos
- ***Algebraic methods in philosophical logic***, Dunn.
- **Algebraic Methods of mathematical logic**, Ladisalv Rieger

Which one do you recommend? feel free to recommend books that I've not mentioned above.

By the way, I know elements of algebraic logic as I've read most of Paul Halmos' ***Logic via Algebra***

Comment: I suggest to add (before Rasiowa's book) : Helena Rasiowa & Roman Sikorski, The Mathematics of Metamathematics (1963)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, Done, I've added another text too "Check the last one"

Comment: Since 2015, the book "Abstract Algebraic Logic, An Introductory Textbook" by Josep Maria Font appeared. I did *not* yet read lots of it or compare it to the other books mentioned here. But I think it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

*Some comments...*

I suggest you to consider also :

- JDonald Monk, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=WSTdnQEACAAJ) (1976);

it is a "standard" textbook with : *Part I: Recursive Function Theory; Part II: Elements of Logic; Part III: Decidable and Undecidable Theories; Part IV: Model Theory*, but the treatment of mathematical logic has a strong "algebraic" flavour, with a section dedicated to *Cylindric algebras*.

Personally, I **do not** reccomend Paul Halmos, [Algebraic logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=GG3IqlA34E0C&pg=PA5) (1962), because is a collection of separate papers.

About :

- Helena Rasiowa & Roman Sikorski, [The Mathematics of Metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=5pBbnQEACAAJ) (1963),

it  is a "modern classic", very rigorous and complete for *classical* and *intuitionistic* logics; unfortunately, it is quite old (there is no Kripke semantics) and also the symbols used are quite "old-fashioned".

About :

- Donald W. Barnes & John M. Mack, [An Algebraic Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=gEIbPwAACAAJ) (1975),

it is a good textbook, but "limited" to *classical* logic.

Comment: Do you have any comment on "Algebraic methods" by Dunn? or "Algebraic methods in mathematical logic" by Rieger?. For Donald, I think it's not a drawback to consider only classical logic as a "first step into the subject". For "The mathematics of metamathematics" I've checked it and found that it uses topological methods too, not only the algebraic methods. Do you think it's a good text for self-study even with its old-fashioned  notation? At least, to study Algebraic classical logic from it?

Comment: @MathsLover - I think that Donald Barnes & John Mack is simpler to begin with ... But R&S Math of Metamath is abcolutely self-contained and rigorous; it ia huge but not "difficult".

Comment: Ah, cool, Do you think I need some training with topology before reading it? I've already studied some basics of topology from Munkres, I don't know if what I've is already sufficient.

Comment: @MathsLover - I think that the "quantity of topology" needed is quite little; you can browse your topology textbook if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as always the choice of appropriate book depends on your motivations for studying algebraic logic. Although my knowledge of it is very superficial it seems to me you have not received many recommendations so let me comment briefly.

I only skimmed through *Algebraic methods in philosophical logic* by Dunn and Hardegree but it seemed to me that it is easy to read. However, it does not cover the algebraization of FOL. For that see cylindric algebras (e.g. two volumes by Henkin, Monk, and Tarski), complete lattices (e.g. book by Rasiowa and Sikorski), Halmos (polyadic) algebras or some other approaches.

*The mathematics of metamathematics* by Rasiowa and Sikorski and *An algebraic approach to non-classical logics* by Rasiowa are classics. If I remember it correctly the later provides a more general approach and the former deals mainly with classical and intuitionistic logic.

It is worth of mentioning that Rieger's book *Algebraic methods of mathematical logic* is based on complete but unlikely final manuscript found after author's premature death.

If you are interested in so-called abstract algebraic logic in general setting then *Protoalgebraic logic* by Czelakowski is a useful source. There are also some survey papers and influential monograph *Algebraizable logics* by Blok and Pigozzi.